# ThreadPoolExecutor: threads (futures) do not release memory when completed and the results are yielded

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, python-multithreading

I am facing memory issues during downloading large data sets from paginated API responses in python.
When I tried to parallelize the download of multiple pages using ThreadPoolExecutor, I noticed that the finished and resolved futures do not release its memory footprint.

I tried to simplify it in following 2 examples. The first one downloads all pages using ThreadPoolExecutor with `max_workers` set to 1 (this should have the same memory footprint as a simple loop as far as I understand):

```py
from random import random
from concurrent.futures  import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import gc

TOTAL_PAGES = 60 

def download_data(page: int = 1) -> list[float]:
    # Send a request to some resource to get data
    print(f"Downloading page {page}.")
    return [random() for _ in range(1000000)] # mock some larga data sets

def threadpool_memory_test(): 
    processed_pages = 0
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        future_to_page = {
            executor.submit(download_data, page): page for page in range(1, TOTAL_PAGES + 1)
        }
        
        for future in as_completed(future_to_page):
            records = future.result()
            # Do something with the downloaded data..
            processed_pages += 1
            print(f"Downloaded page: {processed_pages} / {TOTAL_PAGES} (number: {future_to_page[future]}) with {len(records)} records.")
            gc.collect() # just to be sure gc is called

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threadpool_memory_test()
```

However when running this script and plotting the memory footprint, it looks like this:
[image: memory fooprint of threadpool]
The futures do not release their memory even when looped through with `as_completed` and obtaining the results.

When I download and process the pages in simple loop. The memory footprint is as expected:

```py
from random import random

TOTAL_PAGES = 60 
def download_data(page: int = 1) -> list[float]:
    # Send a request to some resource to get data
    print(f"Downloading page {page}.")
    return [random() for _ in range(1000000)] # mock some larga data sets

def loop_memory_test():
    for page in range(1, TOTAL_PAGES + 1):
        records = download_data(page)
        # Do something with the downloaded data..
        print(f"Downloaded page: {page} / {TOTAL_PAGES} with {len(records)} records.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop_memory_test()
```

Memory footprint of such script:
[image: memory footprint of simple loop]

Is there a way how to release memory of a future from which the results were already obtained?

I am testing this on macOs Monterey version 12.5 (21G72)

Comment: Just a guess but the future_to_page dictionary still retains references to the futures even though you're acquiring the results. Try building a list of the futures then, once your submission have completed, pop them off the list and see if that makes a difference. What are you using to monitor the memory usage?

Comment: Thank you @Stuart!! That actually worked. I will post separate answer for clarity with updated script.
As for the memory profiler, I am using [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/#:~:text=Time%2Dbased%20memory%20usage), specifically its `Time-based memory usage` feature

Comment: Same issue here!

Answer (score 6):

Based on Stuart's comment I updated the script and it now works as expected (it is also 10x faster as well as uses fraction of the memory):

```py
from random import random
from concurrent.futures  import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import gc

TOTAL_PAGES = 60 

def download_data(page: int = 1) -> list[float]:
    # Send a request to some resource to get data
    print(f"Downloading page {page}.")
    return [random() for _ in range(1000000)] # mock some larga data sets

def threadpool_memory_test(): 
    processed_pages = 0
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        future_to_page = {
            executor.submit(download_data, page): page for page in range(1, TOTAL_PAGES + 1)
        }

        for future in as_completed(future_to_page):
            records = future.result()
            page = future_to_page.pop(future)
            # Do something with the downloaded data..
            processed_pages += 1
            print(f"Downloaded page: {processed_pages} / {TOTAL_PAGES} (number: {page}) with {len(records)} records.")
            gc.collect() # just to be sure gc is called

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threadpool_memory_test()
```

It boils down just to this line:

```py
page = future_to_page.pop(future)
```

making sure the reference to the future is removed.

The memory footprint now:
[image: memory footprint of updated threadpool test script]

Thank you!

Comment: Where is Stuart comment?

Comment: what is the advantage of having an explicit gc.collect()? What's the performance without that?

Comment: Can you post Stuart's comment please?

Comment: The future_to_page dictionary still retains references to the futures even though they have acquired the results. Need to remove it with `future_to_page.pop(future)`.